# Declare an ENUM in a Typescript Definition File

Tags: typescript, netsuite

So, I'm building a d.ts file for SuiteScript 2.0  How can I define an ENUM in a d.ts file?  I've read that it needs to live in a .ts file, but I don't want the TS compiler emitting the ENUM, only define/validate against my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an enum in a d.ts file, but since those files generate no runtime, the compiler will just replace the enum names with their values.

This means that enum values must be constant. You also can not use enum names as strings.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/432) for details.